# What does the hebrew/biblical number 57 mean?

Tags: number

I heard the hebrew number/character for 47 is 'what', but what is does the number 57 mean? Also where can I learn about the other numbers?

Comment: זן he feeds....

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us! For other numbers see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series)

Comment: The word מה, meaning what, has the numerical value of 45.